# MongoDb Query Nested Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Edit: Problem solved - Used AlexisG's answer**

I'm trying to query the following Schema:

```js
{
    "a1": {

        "a1_1": "1",
        "a1_2": "2",
        "a1_3": "3"

    },
    "a2": {
    "a2_1": "1"
    }
}
```

What's the query required to get to "a1_1"?

**My Attempts:**

```js
1. let findItem = await MyModel.findOne({'a1.a1_1' : '1'});
2. let findItem = await MyModel.findOne({a1:{a1_1 : '1'}});
```

**The Error I'm getting:**

```js
ValidatorError: Path `a1.a1_1` is required.
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
{"a1.a1_1": "1"}
```

This will try to find documents where field `a1_1` inside `a1` is equal to "1"

```
{"a1": {"a1_1": "1"}}
```

However, this will try to find documents where `a1` is equal to inside `{"a1_1": "1"}`. And hence there is there should be nothing else in the `a1` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const record = await db.collection('yourCollectionNameHere')
.findOne(
            {"a1": {"a1_1": "1"}}
        );
```

Edit:
Sample with database connection:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const uri = process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING; // Your mongodb connection url
    
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

await client.connect();
const db = await client.db();
const record = await db.collection('yourCollectionNameHere')
.findOne(
            {"a1": {"a1_1": "1"}}
        );
```

Comment: 'db.collection' is not a function

where db is:
mongoose.connect(.....)

Comment: In your case, you should use `MyModel.findOne()`

Comment: let findItem = await MyModel.findOne({"a1":{"a1_1" : '1'}});

Like so? or am I missing something?

Comment: @GoFast I edited my answer. I think your db connection is incorrect